# N++ throwing error while compiling the C# program using NppExec plugin?

Tags: c#, nppexec

I have wrote a program to check the N++ that if it works with C# programs to execute directly within it, I set it up using NppExec plugin and set the path for the script is

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /out:"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
>   "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe"

my simple written program to check it is,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
      {
      sayHello();
      Console.Read();
      }

       static void SayHello()
       {
       Console.Write("Hello World!, I'm practicing at the moment.");
       }
```

When I compile it hitting <kbd>F6</kbd> it throws the error

> Process started >>> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version
>   3.5.30729.4926 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> My_practice.cs(12,4): error CS0103: The name 'sayHello' does not exist
>   in the current context
>    <<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
>   "D:\My_practice.cs.exe" CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
>    The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

While there is no error in my program checking on VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. The `sayHello()` call should be `SayHello()`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   //sayHello();   <-- Invalid due to lowercase "s"
   SayHello();
   Console.Read();
}

static void SayHello()
{
   Console.Write("Hello World!, I'm practicing at the moment.");
}
```

Comment: Hahahahahah I'm very stupid and blind enough to not see that minor mistake.